Solvability and Derivatives in a System of Equations Using the Implicit Function Theorem
Problem. Show that the system of equations
$$ xu + yvu^2 = 2 \quad \text{and} \quad xu^3 + y^2v^4 = 2 $$
in a neighborhood around $ P = (-1, -1, -1, -1) $ is solvable for $ u $ and $ v $ as functions in terms of $ x $ and $ y $. Calculate at the point $ P $ the derivatives $ \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} $, $ \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} $, $ \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} $, and $ \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} $.
Solution. Let us generate a function $ F : \mathbb{R}^{2+2} \to \mathbb{R}^2 $ defined as:
$$ F(x, y, u, v) = \begin{pmatrix} xu + yvu^2 - 2 \\ xu^3 + y^2v^4 - 2 \end{pmatrix} $$
Then, we have satisfied the condition for the implicit function theorem, since:
$$ \det\left( \frac{\partial F}{\partial (u, v)} \bigg|_P \right) \neq 0 $$
Now we find open neighborhoods which satisfy the condition $ F(x, y, u(x,y), v(x,y)) = 0 $. By implicit differentiation, we find that:
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} F(x, y, u, v) =
\begin{pmatrix}
F^1_x & F^1_y & F^1_u & F^1_v \\
F^2_x & F^2_y & F^2_u & F^2_v
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\ 0 \\ \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \\ \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}
\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\ 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Similarly, we differentiate with respect to $ y $:
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial y} F(x, y, u, v) =
\begin{pmatrix}
F^1_x & F^1_y & F^1_u & F^1_v \\
F^2_x & F^2_y & F^2_u & F^2_v
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\ 1 \\ \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \\ \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}
\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\ 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
By evaluating the derivatives at the point $ P $ and solving the system of linear equations, we get the following results:
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = -\frac{1}{3}, \quad \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = \frac{1}{3}, \quad \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} = 0, \quad \text{and} \quad \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} = -\frac{1}{3}
$$
Question. I am new to the implicit function theorem and wonder if I have used it correctly. Comments affirming or disproving my procedure are welcome. Thanks a lot!

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solution-verification: For posts looking for feedback or verification of a proposed solution. "Is my proof correct?" is too broad or missing context. Instead, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof is in doubt, and why so.

You used the theorem correctly, and I find the same as you for $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$ but not for $\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$ and $\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$. May be you did some calculation mistake, or it's me.
